# move image from class

Tags: javascript, html

How do i access the image from a class in html5 canvas?
 I load an image from a class but to access and move it across the canvas I cant get access to it. I can do this without a class.

The code works fine without a class.

```
          <script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img1_x=10;
  var img1_y=10;
  ctx.font="14px Arial"; 


  //this is how you do classes
 //this is how you do classes
function ClassLoadImages(name1) {
  var img1 = new Image();
  this.x=img1_x;
  this.y=img1_y;
  this.name1=name1;
  img1.src = name1;


  img1.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img1, img1_x,  img1_y);

 };

//add this
 this.imgElement = img1;
};//func

  ClassLoadImages.prototype.m_move = function(){
     img1_x++;
   img1_y++;
      ctx.drawImage(img.imgElement,  img1_x,   img1_y);
     // ctx.fillText("finished loading " ,10,40);
  };


 function doGameLoop() {

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
    img.m_move();
     if (img1_x>30)
     {
          clearInterval(gameLoop);

     }
 }




  var img= new ClassLoadImages('images/image4.jpg');
 gameLoop = setInterval(doGameLoop, 100);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the image element that was created in the constructor then you just need to add the `new Image` to `this`:

```
//this is how you do classes
function ClassLoadImages(name1) {
    var img1 = new Image();
    this.x=10;
    this.y=10;
    this.name1=name1;
    img1.src = name1;


    img1.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img1, img1_x,  img1_y);

    };

    //add this
    this.imgElement = img1;
};//func
```

Then you can reference it from the object via `img.imgElement`.

If you mean you can't move the object being referenced then there is also a typo in the public method you added - `ClassMoveImages.prototype.m_move` should be `ClassLoadImages.prototype.m_move` in order to have access to the attributes of the object you created.